# Hide tr if its td:nth-child() first letter not contains letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

all want is to hide tr if first letter of td:nth-child(1) not contains letter D,
atm my code just hides it if its all tds not contain letter D.
HTML:

**HTML**

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Name</th><th>Lastname</th></tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Zuri</td><td>Mam</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Dima</td><td>Mam</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Dato</td><td>Mik</td></tr>
        <tr><td>AMD</td><td>Phen</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button id="hide">Filter by First letter D</button>
<button id="showAll">Show All</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#hide").click( function() { 
    $("#myTable tr:not(:has(th))").not(":contains(D)").hide();
});
$("#showAll").click( function() { 
    $("#myTable tr:not(:has(th))").show() 
});
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryCm5/).
Please help, 
Thank you!

Comment: get the td html() and and check only the first character is D or not

Comment: don't use contains , it checks the whole string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) checks whether the string is present anywhere in the content, you can use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter the `tr` elements

```
$("#hide").click(function () {
    $("#myTable tbody tr").filter(function(){
        return $.trim($(this).find('td:first-child').text()).charAt(0) != 'D'
    }).hide();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FwXsk/)

Comment: Here this condition is ok return $.trim($(this).find('td:first-child').text()).charAt(0) != 'D'.    But problem in  Fiddle...

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
$("#hide").click( function() { 
    $("#myTable tbody tr").each(function(){
        if($(this).find("td:first").text().substr(0,1).toUpperCase() == 'D'){   
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });       
});

$("#showAll").click( function() { $("#myTable tbody tr").show() });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pesulap/ryCm5/1/